# Define transitionTo in Emberjs component

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I've a component which is being used at several routes. 
Now in that component I want to use swipeLeft and swipeRight events from ember-gestures library.

When i try alert messages they get fired on both events. But when I try to run 
`this.transitionTo('someRoute', dynamicPart)` then it doesn't get fired.

I get `Uncaught TypeError: this.transitionTo is not a function(…)` error.

How can I use `transitionTo()` from Ember-component?

---

I have 3 routes(tours, schedule, soc) and have 3 tabs on ui for that.
I'm calling activity-details component each time to display all details of that activity. Here is the code for that:
    // activity-details :: component

```
 next: Ember.computed('listOfThisTypeOfActivities', 'currentActivityId',      function(){
      |> Logic to find out the next activity 
      |> Simply grabbing the currentActivityId and then getting the next item from the listOfThisTypeOfActivities
     }),
    // Similarly I have 'prev' computed property

    swipeRight(next){
      console.log('Right Swipe' ); // this works
      // alert(next.id);
      this.transitionTo('schedule', next.id);
    },

    swipeLeft(e){
      this.transitionTo('schedule', prev.id); // this doesn't work
    },
```

I want to swipe between these activities. i.e. if I'm at `schedule/1` then on swipe event i should be navigated to `schedule/2` route.

The other problem is => I have 3 types of activities: Social Activities, Schedule, Tours (and each one have its own route). Hence it seems wrong to write `next` and `prev` computed properties in component itself. 
Also we don't use ember-data, this list of activities are coming from services. 
Each route(/tours/, /schedule/) has it's own list of activities.(i.e. tours and schedule both are nothing but activity only).

---

### Update

After @torazaburo and @Patsy Issa and @kumkanilam's suggestions:
1. I have moved `next` and `prev` computed properties to the controller.
2. I have moved the logic for route-navigation to controller with the help of closure actions.
3. It's all working.

Though I've written roughly similar code in all 3 controllers, I'm sure it can be improved. I just don't know how. But I'm very happy that I'm able to make it work.

Thanks a lot @torazaburo, @patsyIssa and @kumkanilam for your feedback and showing me the better way.

Comment: How about trying `Ember.getOwner(this).lookup('controller:application').transitionToRoute` or try `ember-route-action-helper` addon

Comment: It's better to keep components isolated from navigation. Have your component return an action which is handled by the invoker.

Comment: Components are meant to be isolated. As @torazaburo said trigger an action and handle the redirection in a controller/route.

Comment: You cannot use transitionTo within a component; since the component does not have the corresponding method. What I should suggest is you send an action to the route and use transitionTo within the route.

Comment: @kumkanillam No, don't do that.

Comment: @torazaburo Yes you are right. Pls dont do the transition inside component methods.... My suggestions goes to ember-route-action helper addon. Thats the way to go. In longer run DDAU approach will save you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.transitionTo` is a route-specific method. Under the hood it calls the private Ember router service. You will either need to inject the private routing service into your component (which could break once the new Ember router is released) or send your transition requests up to actions in your route.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I need to send the action from component to controller.
And in that action I need to use this.transitionToRoute function.
But by doing that I'm not sure if i can create computed properties in controller the same way I'm doing it in my component currently.

Comment: @arpit I don't understand what this has to do with computed properties. If you show a little bit more code, perhaps I could comment.

Comment: Hi @torazaburo ... As you have suggested, i have moved the logic to the controller with the help of closure actions. I wrote the same logic 3 times in 3 different controllers but it's working now☺

Comment: @acorncom - I ended up moving all logic to controller. And then I use `this.transitionToRoute` method from controllers.